# C++ PackageKit newb linking issue

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to import PackageKit into a C++ project I'm working with (as a C++ newbie coming from a mostly Java background). My goal is do some things with the packages I have installed on my system.

I've installed `libpackagekit-glib2-16`, `libpackagekit-glib2-dev`, `libpackagekit-qt2-6`, `libpackagekit-qt2-dev`, and `packagekit` (I know I won't need all of these down the line, but I'm just covering my bases for now). I can see that they've been installed here: `/usr/include/PackageKit` which has the subfolders `packagekit-glib2`, `packagekit-qt2`, `plugin`.

To help me along I'm using qt 5.2.1 to act as a crutch for my Makefiles while I'm still learning, but I'm not actually using any qt resources for now. I've been able to import apt's and dpkg's libraries previously via `-lapt-lib` and `-ldpkg` under qt's `LIBS+=` but I can't figure out how to import the packagekit's library (I've tried multiple variations, but I can't figure out how to properly import this library).

This:

```
#define I_KNOW_THE_PACKAGEKIT_GLIB2_API_IS_SUBJECT_TO_CHANGE
#include <PackageKit/packagekit-glib2/packagekit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Results with this:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../console-example -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o main.o ../console-example/main.cpp
In file included from ../console-example/main.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/PackageKit/packagekit-glib2/packagekit.h:31:41: fatal error: packagekit-glib2/pk-catalog.h: No such file or directory
 #include <packagekit-glib2/pk-catalog.h>
```

If this is necessary, my system is `Ubuntu 14.04 64bit` and as I've mentioned I'm using `qt 5.2.1` to help with the makefile. Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within my qt project's .pro file I had to make the following additions to get it to compile and link.

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig # This enables the next line
PKGCONFIG = gtk+-2.0     # This will link against gtk+-2.0

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/PackageKit/ \  # This is the include for packagekit
    += /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include/          # This will include glib, which packagekit is dependent on
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a compilation problem. The compiler cannot find packagekit's headers. I suppose that into g++ line you need to add `-I/usr/include/PackageKit` or something similar.